# Django - How to get a custom user model with get_object_or_404

Tags: django

I'd like to retrieve an instance of my `User` class, which extends `AbstractBaseUser` . I'd also like to filter my users by a primary key using the django `get_object_or_404` shortcut, but this won't work:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.conf import settings

user = get_object_or_404(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, pk=pk)
```

The following exception is raised:

```
"ValueError at /v1/users/24c47b4a-920e-47c7-902c-80c64c0dd657/
First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'str'.
```

In my `settings.py`, this is what my `AUTH_USER_MODEL` looks like:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this `get_user_model`;

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.conf import settings

user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use this solution:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.conf import settings

user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=pk)
```